# How to draw half of a rectangle above a greek letter in math mode?

Tags: generic

Today the prof. a new sign and I don't know how to draw it. It is like overline, but on both ends of the line go down, so there is half of a rectangle above the letter. Does anyone know, how to make it in Latex?

Comment: `mathtools` provides `\overbracket`.  Here's an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461939

Comment: Thank you, exactly, what I was looking for!